# ¿cómo puedo realizar la siguiente consulta mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

He estado tratando de realizar la siguiente consulta "Devuelve un listado con los nombres de los fabricantes y el número de productos que tienen cada uno con un precio superior o igual a 220. El listado debe mostrar el nombre de todos los fabricantes, es decir, si hay algún fabricante que no tiene productos con un precio superior o igual a 220 deberá aparecer en el listado con un valor igual a 0 en el número de productos."

```
CREATE TABLE fabricante (
  codigo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE producto (
  codigo INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  precio DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  codigo_fabricante INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (codigo_fabricante) REFERENCES fabricante(codigo)
);

INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(1, 'Asus');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(2, 'Lenovo');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(3, 'Hewlett-Packard');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(4, 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(5, 'Seagate');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(6, 'Crucial');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(7, 'Gigabyte');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(8, 'Huawei');
INSERT INTO fabricante VALUES(9, 'Xiaomi');

INSERT INTO producto VALUES(1, 'Disco duro SATA3 1TB', 86.99, 5);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(2, 'Memoria RAM DDR4 8GB', 120, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(3, 'Disco SSD 1 TB', 150.99, 4);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(4, 'GeForce GTX 1050Ti', 185, 7);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(5, 'GeForce GTX 1080 Xtreme', 755, 6);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(6, 'Monitor 24 LED Full HD', 202, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(7, 'Monitor 27 LED Full HD', 245.99, 1);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(8, 'Portátil Yoga 520', 559, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(9, 'Portátil Ideapd 320', 444, 2);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(10, 'Impresora HP Deskjet 3720', 59.99, 3);
INSERT INTO producto VALUES(11, 'Impresora HP Laserjet Pro M26nw', 180, 3);
```

Lo único que he logrado hasta ahora es una consulta que me arroja la cuenta de cuántos tienen un precio superior a 220 o igual, pero sólo de aquellos que tienen algún producto con dicha cantidad. Y aún no logro que aparezcan también los que no tienen ningún producto con precio mayor o igual a 220.

```
select f.nombre,COUNT(f.nombre) from fabricante as f
join producto as p on p.codigo_fabricante = f.codigo
where p.precio >= 220
group by f.nombre;

+---------+-----------------+
| nombre  | COUNT(f.nombre) |
+---------+-----------------+
| Asus    |               1 |
| Crucial |               1 |
| Lenovo  |               2 |
+---------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Después de una revisión del ejercicio lo orienté a este resultado:

```
SELECT fabricante.nombre,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN producto.precio >= 220 THEN fabricante.nombre ELSE NULL END) AS N
FROM fabricante 
LEFT JOIN producto
ON fabricante.codigo = producto.codigo_fabricante
GROUP BY fabricante.nombre;
```

- Hago uso de `LEFT JOIN` para además de los datos relacionados entonces incluir los nombre de fabricantes que no están relacionados con algún producto del lado de la derecha es decir en la tabla producto
- Hago uso de un `CASE WHEN` para evaluar cuando el precio de producto es mayor o igual a 220 y entonces muestro el nombre del fabricante en caso contrario `NULL`

Dando este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4):

solucionado tomando todos los fabricantes con un **`LEFT JOIN`** y una subconsulta agrupando. y el **`IF`** es para pasar los **`NULL`** a cero.

```
select a.nombre,if(consulta.cuantos IS NULL,0,consulta.cuantos) as cantidad 
from fabricante a
left outer join (select codigo_fabricante,count(*) as cuantos 
                 from producto  where precio >= 220
                 group by codigo_fabricante ) as consulta 
                 on a.codigo = consulta.codigo_fabricante
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT f2.nombre, 0 FROM fabricante f2 WHERE f2.nombre <> ALL (select f.nombre from fabricante as f
join producto as p on p.codigo_fabricante = f.codigo
where p.precio >= 220
group by f.nombre) UNION (select f.nombre,COUNT(f.nombre) from fabricante as f
join producto as p on p.codigo_fabricante = f.codigo
where p.precio >= 220
group by f.nombre)
```

Esta forma funciona, no creo que sea la mejor igual, pero no tengo mas tiempo

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas crear un alias para tabla derivada

```
SELECT fabricante.nombre, COUNT(consulta.codigo_fabricante) AS 'total'
FROM fabricante LEFT JOIN (SELECT producto.codigo_fabricante
                            FROM producto 
                            WHERE producto.precio >= 220) AS consulta
ON fabricante.codigo = consulta.codigo_fabricante
GROUP BY fabricante.codigo;
```